# Firebase Cloud Function: How to write a document reference path String using various IDs in JS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.updateDailyOrderCount = functions.firestore
    .document("past_orders/{uid}/{mid}/{orderId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const orderData = snapshot.data();
      const orderTimestamp = orderData.timestamp.toDate();
      const formattedDate = formatDate(orderTimestamp);

      const mid = context.params.mid;
      const totalAmount = orderData.paymentDetails.totalAmount;
      const profit = orderData.paymentDetails.profit;
      console.log("formatted date:", formattedDate);
      const url = "order_reports/daily/${mid}/${formattedDate}";

      const dailyCounterRef = admin.firestore().doc(url);

      return dailyCounterRef.set({
        count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        totalAmount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(totalAmount),
        profit: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(profit),
        date: formattedDate}, {merge: true});
    });
```

I have the above code deployed in cloud functions. Function is working but saving document as ${mid} and sub collection as ${formattedDate} instead of the actual values of those String interpolations. I have checked and the values are not empty. How to write this document reference correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template literals must be delimited with backtick (`) characters, as explained in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

So changing

```
const url = "order_reports/daily/${mid}/${formattedDate}";
```

to

```
const url = `order_reports/daily/${mid}/${formattedDate}`;
```

should do the trick.

---

Side Note : I would call this variable `docPath` instead of `url`.